# Multiple Cell Editing within a Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, grid, data-entry

So I'm looking for a way to allow a user to enter numbers and dates into a grid of cells in bulk. What would be ideal is if they could simply highlight/select a range of cells, type "42" or "12/31/2010", and move on and then "42" or "12/31/2010" would exist in every cell. This is kinda like entering data into Excel that we're trying to mimic but we don't need a true spreadsheet-like control here.

So are there any third-party solutions that do this? As far as I can tell, Telerik, Infragistics, and all of the other usual third-party component vendors don't provide such a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar with custom jQuery:

[Hierarchical Table Manipulation with jQuery](http://blog.devlpr.net/2010/01/07/hierarchical-table-manipulation-with-jquery/)

Comment: How do I select multiple cells with that? Seems to just hide/show rows and columns.

Comment: Do some reading on jQuery selectors and look at the example more closely.  You will see that I am applying functionality generally across specific DOM object(textboxes) via CSS class names.  You could do the same to propagate your changes across rows and or columns.

Comment: Ooooh, you want me to think instead of just allowing you to hand me a solution. I see.. ;)  I'll take another look into this. Thanks! :)